# Find http:// in string where not preceded by a space

Tags: mysql, regex

I am looking for a regex for MySQL which will find a row where the following:

**Will match:**
`this is texthttp:// and no space before http`

**Won't match:**
`this is text http:// but has a space so is happy`

I tried `WHERE message REGEXP '[\s]http:'` and for some reason this found some but I know its not all the instances. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match strings containing a 'nonspace' character before `http://`:

```
regexp '[^[:space:]]http://';
```

See [mysql regexp documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html).

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------------------+
| s                |
+------------------+
| texthttp://text  |
| http://text      |
| text http://text |
| texthttp://      |
| text http://     |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test where s regexp '[^[:space:]]http://';
+-----------------+
| s               |
+-----------------+
| texthttp://text |
| texthttp://     |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af234/2)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why not (see example)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This matches as well and works as expected. Did you understand the question? He's obviously trying to find broken broken links in some column.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys but thanks for your help and question solved!